# Git unable to push to remote repository: "Read-only file system"

Tags: git, unix, version-control, repository

Trying to push to a remote repository gives me the error:

> error: unable to create temporary sha1 filename : Read-only file system

Funny enough, it worked perfectly fine for the push 30 minutes earlier. Another thing worth noting is that **I'm the only one pushing/commiting/accessing this repository**.

SSHing into my repository server trying to `chown`, `chmod`, copy, rename etc the repository, I keep getting the error `Read-only file system`.  Listing the owner of the repository by using `ls -ld my-repo.git` yields:

> drwxrwsr-x 7 my_user users 248 Jul 20 14:56 my-repo.git/

Looks proper, owned by me, right? I don't understand why this is happening. Any suggestions on how to solve this extremely annoying problem would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your disk broke and the OS remounted it as readonly to save it. see /var/log/messages and the output of "mount" to confirm.

Comment: A possibility.  Try rebooting the box.  It might want to fsck itself too.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as "your disk broke", but it definitely sounds like the operating system hit some kind of error and remounted the disk as read-only. Rebooting is a good idea.

Comment: dont reboot yet. clone the repo to another machine first and confirm that the disk has had an error

Comment: with "disk broke" I mean that the disk probably had an unrecoverable read or write error , or the filesystem was detected to be somehow corrupted.

Comment: The `/var/log/messages` file seems to be empty.. Hmm, I tried to remount the folder, however, > mount: only root can do that. I guess I have to contact my host and ask them to re-mount the repository..?

Comment: so you cant do a "mount" with no arguments? I can do it on my linux box without superuser privileges

Comment: but do a backup of it first by doing a clone !

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen If he's trying to push to the remote repository, he must already have a local clone.

Comment: yes but it is not a naked clone probably ? also it is not necessarily a full clone? anyways...

Comment: Also contact your provider and tell them what happened and that you think that it is a disk error.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! @MarkusMikkolainen Executing `mount` without any arguments yielded the following output (or rather, error?): http://pastebin.com/caix8Cui

Comment: ok so mount is telling old data too. your root filesystem seems to be corrupted since /etc is unwritable. contact your provider and give them this info.

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen Matches quite good since there was a server error last night wich killed the whole server. `cat /proc/mounts` yields: http://pastebin.com/zQDd2sUj

Comment: yes. / is reiserfs mounted ro. so then start calling your provider and tell them the reason for the server dying ;)

Comment: Sigh, my whole server is down now. Again. Thank you so much for your help, it's really appreciated!!